# How to integrate this native SDK in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, integration

There is a subscription system called piano which provides native SDK for building mobile apps, but my requirement is to build this app in flutter, but I’m unable to integrate this native sdk since i receive data asynchronously in this sdk:
https://github.com/tinypass/piano-sdk-for-android/blob/master/composer/README.md

Is there anyway to integrate this?

Comment: Why not invoke Native->Flutter methods on those event handlers? In essence, pass the event up into Dart and handle it there. (Just be sure to invoke the Native->Flutter method on the main looper.)

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I never came across this thought. Will try this and share my result.

Comment: @AkashR I created a method in the native part and I called it from flutter but it returns a nullpointer exception.

Comment: @OussamaRidéne Can you share your code ? If you have connected the ```methodChannels``` and initiated them in the right way, you would have got the expected results.

Comment: @AkashR , I'm using pianoID for social connect , this is the method :
final ActivityResultLauncher<PianoIdClient.SignInContext> authResult = registerForActivityResult(
                new PianoIdAuthResultContract(), ...

Comment: and then I launch it : 
authResult.launch( PianoId.signIn());
I test it with with a native android application and it works fine but flutter shows me this exception : java.lang.NullPointerException 
when I call the method